# Django HttpResponseRedirect doesn´t lead to the page

Tags: python, django, redirect, cs50

I am working on the CS50 project2 commerce. I try to create a new list but when I click on the submit button, it doesn´t redirect to the index page as I want. Anybody can help please? I get the error message: auctions.models.Category.DoesNotExist: Category matching query does not exist. However I can add list directly from admin page.

views.py

```
def createlisting(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    allCategories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
        "categories": allCategories
    })
else:
    # get the data from the form
    title = request.POST["title"]
    description = request.POST["description"]
    imageurl = request.POST["imageurl"]
    price = request.POST["price"]
    category = request.POST["category"]

    currentuser = request.user
    # get the contents 
    categoryData = Category.objects.get(categoryName=category)

    #create new list object
    newListing = Listing(
        title=title,
        description=description,
        imageUrl=imageurl,
        price=float(price),
        category=categoryData,
        owner=currentuser
    )
    newListing.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

[image]

create.html

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h2>Create New Listing</h2>

<form action = "{% url 'create' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter Description">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageurl">Image URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="imageurl" class="form-control" id="imageurl" placeholder="Image Url">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Choose a Category</label>
        <select name="category" id="category">
            {% for category in categories %}
                <option value="category">{{category}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create New Listing</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: At first, refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74016844/17562044) answer, also share html too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). And you don't need to use else after returning in the if statement.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def createlisting(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        allCategories = Category.objects.all()
        return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
            "categories": allCategories
        })
    # POST
    title = request.POST["title"]
    description = request.POST["description"]
    imageurl = request.POST["imageurl"]
    price = request.POST["price"]
    category = request.POST["category"]

    currentuser = request.user
    # get the contents 
    categoryData = Category.objects.get(categoryName=category)

    #create new list object
    newListing = Listing(
        title=title,
        description=description,
        imageUrl=imageurl,
        price=float(price),
        category=categoryData,
        owner=currentuser
    )
    newListing.save()
    return redirect("index")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried the same as you do, still submit button doesn´t lead to the index and remains in the same page...

Answer (score 0):

Try this view:

```py
def createlisting(request):
    allCategories=""
    if request.method == "GET":
        allCategories = Category.objects.all()
    else:
        # get the data from the form
        title = request.POST["title"]
        description = request.POST["description"]
        imageurl = request.POST["imageurl"]
        price = request.POST["price"]
        category = request.POST["category"]

        currentuser = request.user
        # get the contents 
        categoryData = Category.objects.get(categoryName=category)

        #create new list object
        newListing = Listing(
            title=title,
            description=description,
            imageUrl=imageurl,
            price=float(price),
            category=categoryData,
            owner=currentuser
        )
        newListing.save()
        return redirect("index")
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
        "categories": allCategories
    })
```

Comment: it doesn´t work either..

Comment: @bambi Can you share your html form too?

Comment: I added html and put more information on my original post